# The norm of Borel measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was looking on at the [Convolution page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Convolution_of_measures) and saw that it stated that we can define the convolution of two Borel measures of bounded variation on $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\mu$ and $\nu$, to be
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x) d(\mu\ast \nu)(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x+y) d\mu(x) d\nu(y),$$
and that we have the result
$$||\mu \ast \nu || \leq ||\mu|| ||\nu||.$$

I'm not sure what the second statement means though. Is there a natural norm for the space of Borel measures with bounded variation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DJC's answer is of course to the point. I'm adding a short sketch of a proof of the inequality $$\|\mu \ast \nu\| \leq \|\mu\| \,\|\nu\|$$ since you asked about it in a comment. In that comment you mentioned $\sigma$-finiteness.  Note that bounded variation implies that all measures involved are in fact *finite*.

One of the most convenient ways of writing the total variation norms is as

$$\|\mu\| = \sup_{|f| \leq 1}{\;\left|\int f\,d\mu\right|}$$

where it doesn't matter much what kinds of measurable functions $f$ you allow in the supremum (continuous; simple; Borel; smooth; compactly supported or not). I'll take Borel here.

Given this, the inequality is then clear: By Fubini we have for every Borel function $f$ with $|f|\leq 1$ that the function
$$y \longmapsto \left|\int f(x+y)\,d\mu(x)\right|$$
is Borel and bounded by $\|\mu\|$ hence the fact that $\|\nu\| = \| \,|\nu|\,\|$ gives
$$\left|\int f \, d(\mu \ast \nu) \right| = \left|\iint f(x+y)\,d\mu(x)\,d\nu(y)\right| \leq \int\left|\int f(x+y)\,d\mu(x)\right|\,d|\nu|(y) \leq \|\mu\| \,\|\nu\|.$$
The norm of $\|\mu \ast \nu\|$ is by definition the supremum over the left hand side over $|f| \leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I mentioned $\sigma$-finiteness is because I wanted to verify that you couldn't get the inequality for just any two infinite measures (in particular ones that aren't $\sigma$-finite). Also, if the measures in question are positive, do you still need to use Fubini, or can you use some sort of product measure notion to say that $f \equiv 1$ would be the function we use and so the norm of the convolution would be equal to the product of each of the two measures on the whole space?

Comment: Also, does that alternate definition only work for Borel measures? Is there an easy way to see why we can use any of those types of functions to define the norm? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: A quick first reaction to the second comment: The usual definition of total variation (see e.g. Rudin's book on real and complex analysis) involves cutting up the domain of the measure in disjoint pieces $E_i$ and maximizing $|\sum a_i \mu E_i|$ where $|a_i| = 1$. Now if we're working with (regular) *Borel* measures we can approximate the $E_i$ with open sets $U_{i}$ from the outside and the characteristic functions of the $U_i$ with functions from any of those classes from below. Is this enough as a hint for that?

Comment: Hm, yeah I think I get it. So does that mean the the definition you used only works for regular measures?

Comment: Two things: Yes, I believe that it is fair to say that you only want to do it for (finite) Borel measures. However, every such is automatically regular (and tight) on complete separable metric spaces. Note also that a finite measure automatically has a certain integrability condition built in. As much as you can't convolve any two (non-negative) functions without getting something meaningless, you can't do it with any two measures. Note that in working on $\mathbb{R}^n$ we're working on a space with lot of structure. In particular it has a group structure and a translation invariant measure.

Comment: Secondly, you have a topology (locally compact) that you also exploit when speaking of Borel, continuous (let alone smooth) functions.

Comment: Cool! I'm not familiar with the result that finite Borel measures are regular and tight on complete separable metric spaces. Is that hard to show?

Comment: It's rather easy. See e.g. Kechris, *[Classical descriptive set theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=pPv9KCEkklsC&pg=PA107)* section 17.C, theorems 17.10 and 17.11. page 107 (link should go directly to that page on Google Books). It's also in most of the serious texts on measure theory.

Answer (score 4):

[Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation#Measures_of_bounded_variation).  Generally, $\| \mu\|$ is defined as

$$
\| \mu \| = |\mu|(\mathbb{R}^d),
$$

where $|\mu |$ is the *total* variation.

Comment: That definition should be well-defined for every signed(not necessarily being Borel) measure  right? Also, using that definition, does the convolution inequality then come from using applying Fubini's Theorem (like the way it would if the two measures were absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure)? You would also need the $\sigma$-finite property in that case then right?