# Is $\sup_{\| f \| \leq 1}{\left| \int f d\mu \right|} = \sup_{\| f \| \leq 1}{\{ |\mu(f)| \}}?$

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59521/the-norm-of-borel-measures) given by t.b. mentioned the following

> One of the most convenient way of writing a total variation norm is
>
> $$\| \mu \| = \sup_{\| f \| \leq 1}{\left| \int f d\mu \right|}$$

In this [paper](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf), page $123$, the author mentioned that element of the dual space of real-valued lipschitz functions $Lip_0(X)^*$ can be identify as a measure $\mu$, with the above norm.

By definition of a dual space $Lip_0(X)^*$, every element is an evaluation function $\mu : Lip_0(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$. Then its operator norm is 
$$\| \mu \| = \sup_{\| f \| \leq 1}{\{ |\mu(f)| \}}$$
where $f \in Lip_0(x)$.

Question: Are the two norms the same? In other words, is 
$$\sup_{\| f \| \leq 1}{\left| \int f d\mu \right|} = \sup_{\| f \| \leq 1}{\{ |\mu(f)| \}}?$$

Comment: The supremum in the paper is over $\|f\|_{Lip} \leq 1$ and is unrelated to the total variation. As to the rest of your question, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking: in the paper the stated equality is a consequence of duality.

Comment: Actually I just want to check whether the norm defined on $\mathcal{F}(X)$ is the same as operator norm on evaluation functional.

Comment: As far as I understand, $\mu(f) := \int f\,\mathrm d\mu$, so your question seems trivial.

Comment: @Ilya: can justify your equality?

Comment: @JamesKilbane: But according to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306567/if-mu-is-a-signed-finite-measure-then-mu-sup-left-int-f-d-mu?rq=1, they are the same.

Comment: @JamesKilbane I apologize for the previous statement, it seems that one of them is total variation, not the operator norm.

Comment: This looks like an application of Riesz Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question, but merely an attempt to encourage you to formulate the question in a way that will encourage more attention and answers.

You write:

> By definition of a dual space $Lip_0(X)^*$, every element is an evaluation function $\mu : Lip_0(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$.

*This is not true*. The norm-closure in $Lip_0(X)^{*}$  of the evaluations gives the predual, which is denoted $\mathcal{F}(X)$ in the paper you mentioned. *The predual space is in general not equal to the dual space*. (That's why it has a different name). In fact, a functional $\phi\in Lip_0(X)^{*}$ belongs to the predual of $Lip_0(X)$ if and only if it is continuous in the $w^*$ topology. (See "Lipschitz Algebras" by N. Weaver, p. 36). Also note that on page $123$ the authors *do not* claim that

> All elements of the dual space $Lip_0(X)^{*}$ can be identified with     measures

as readers may understand from your first statement. What is claimed by the authors on page $123$ of the paper you mentioned is the following:

> It is sometimes convenient to think of $\mathcal{F}(X)$ as the completion of the set of Borel measures $\mu$ on $X$ with finite support under the norm
>   $$||\mu||_{\mathcal{F}}=\sup_{||f||_{Lip}\leq 1}\int f\,d\mu$$

Note the words *finite support*. A measure has finite support if an only if it is a linear combination of a finite number of measures concentrated at single points. Not all measures belong to the predual, but only those that are obtained as norm-limits of Cauchy sequences of measures of finite support. The authors then add the following comment on page $123$:

> It now follows that any finite Borel measure supported on a compact subset $K$ of $X$ can be identified with a member of $\mathcal{F}(X)$.

Not *every* Borel measure, but only finite measures with compact support.

So now, you may want to re-formulate your question. What is it exactly that you are asking? I can think of two possible questions:

1. Are you asking whether all Borel measures that belong to the predual $\mathcal{F}(X)$ have a norm given by the supremum over integrals?
2. Are you asking whether that norm, being a supremum taken over Lipschitz functions, coincides with their total variation?

Comment: Can provide me a link to a proof of the statement 'A measure has finite support if an only if it is a linear combination of a finite number of measures concentrated at single points'? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have a link. This is actually very easy to check directly.