# A measure has finite support if and only if it is a linear combination of a finite number of measures concentrated at single points

Tags: measure-theory, dirac-delta

In the answer given by [uniquesolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525319/is-sup-f-leq-1-left-int-f-d-mu-right-sup-f-leq-1/1539448#1539448), there is this statement:

> A measure has finite support if and only if it is a linear combination of a finite number of measures concentrated at single points

Question: How to prove this? I think it should have something to do with dirac measures but I don't know how to start.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you will need some more information about your measureable space. If points are not measurable this will not be true. E.g. if you have the space $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and the $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2,3\}, X\}$ then each measure has finite support but you can never write it as linear combination of measures concentrated on single points if $\mu(\{2,3\})\neq 0$. Because support of a measure is usually defined for a Borel $\sigma$-algebra, I suggest that you start e.g. with a Hausdorff space. I believe this should suffice for the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28measure_theory%29#A_nontrivial_measure_whose_support_is_empty) implies that this is not correct even for Hausdorff spaces and Borel measures. However, under the assumptions of $\mu$ being a Radon measure on a Hausdorff space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, we can prove that it is true:

In this case, we have the important property that the complement of the support has measure zero. Let the finite support be given as
$$\{x\in X| x\in N_x\in \mathcal{T} \Rightarrow \mu(N_x)>0\}=\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}.$$
Because singletons are measurable, and because $\mu(\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}^c)=0$, the measure $\mu$ is uniquely defined by the values $\mu(\{x_i\})$. 
We can now construct measures $\mu_i(A):=\mu(A\cap \{x_i\})$ which are "measures concentrated on a single point." Obviously, we have $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^n\mu_i$ which proves the "only if" dircetion.

The "if" direction is quite trivial: Let $\mu_i$ be measures satisfying $\mu_i(\{x_i\}^c)=0$, then any linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\mu_i$ satisfies $\mu(\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}^c)=0$. Because $X$ is a Hausdorff space, there exists for each $x\notin \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ an open neighborhood $N_x$ such that $N_x \cap \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}=\emptyset$ and thus $x \notin \operatorname{supp}(\mu)$. This implies that the support of $\mu$ is a subset of $\{x_1, \dots , x_n\}$ and, hence, finite.